# Angular Tell other components that there has been a change without using intervals

Tags: angular, angular7

I currently have something like this in the footer component of my project

```
ngOnInit() {

    const checkLocalStorage = interval(15000);
        checkLocalStorage.subscribe(data => {
        // code for checking the Localstorage
    });

}
```

I don't like the idea of having timers looping to check for changes every so many seconds.

I need a simple, clean way to communicate messages to other components (non related component).

I know about **RxStore** is complicated.

I there a simple way to send a simple message to another component telling it to run a method in it's component?

How can I do this without using interval or other loop?

Comment: Use a service that's declared in `app.module`'s `providers` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this event services, to communicate between components.

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

const ServiceName: string = "Events Service";

@Injectable()
export class EventsService implements IEventsService {
    private events = { };

    constructor() { }

    public subscribe(event: string): Observable<any>;
    public subscribe(event: string, callback: (value: any) => void): Subscription;  
    public subscribe(event: string, callback: (value: any) => void, error: (error: any) => void): Subscription;
    public subscribe(event: string, callback: (value: any) => void, error: (error: any) => void, complete: () => void): Subscription;
    public subscribe(event: string, callback?: (value: any) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void) {
        if (!event) {
            throw new Error(`[${ServiceName}] => Subscription method must get event name.`);
        }

        if (this.events[event] === undefined) {
            this.events[event] = new Subject<any>();
        }

        if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
            return this.events[event].asObservable();
        } else {
            return this.events[event].asObservable().subscribe(callback, error, complete);
        }
    }

    public publish(event: string, eventObject?: any) {
        if (!event) {
            throw new Error(`[${ServiceName}] => Publish method must get event name.`);
        } else if (!this.events[event]) {
            return;
        }

        this.events[event].next(eventObject);
    }
}

export interface IEventsService {
    publish(event: string, eventObject?: any);
    subscribe(event: string): Observable<any>;
    subscribe(event: string, callback: (value: any) => void): Subscription;
    subscribe(event: string, callback: (value: any) => void, error: (error: any) => void): Subscription;
    subscribe(event: string, callback: (value: any) => void, error: (error: any) => void, complete: () => void): Subscription;
}

interface ISubscribe{
    (event: string): Observable<any>;
    (event: string, callback: (value: any) => void): Subscription;
    (event: string, callback: (value: any) => void, error: (error: any) => void): Subscription;
    (event: string, callback: (value: any) => void, error: (error: any) => void, complete: () => void): Subscription;
}
```

How to use this service :

publish event from XYZ component

```
   publishNewEvent(){
     this.eventsService.publish("PROFILE_UPDATED");
   }
```

subscribe to an event in ABC component

```
constructor(private eventsService: EventsService){
   this.eventsService.subscribe("PROFILE_UPDATED", () => {
      console.log("Called");
   });
}
```

Comment: It seems to be publishing "publishNewEvent" but how will the other component receive it?

Comment: @PaulC components can receive events after subscribe to event. See code in the constructor.

Comment: So with your code it's a 2 way? You just need to service and to publisher?

Comment: Hey, i've made some changes in answer. If you publish an event from one component, you can listen it on any other component where you want.

Comment: I've getting: this.eventsService.subscribe is not a function

Comment: inject service in the constructor like this, constructor(private eventsService: EventsService){}

Comment: Sorted now. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That is what Angular's [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) is made for. Using `@Input` to pass data into a component and `@Output` to notify a parent about a childs event.

If you have an app structure that makes this too complicated, you would want to think about using [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).

If that is too complicated or over-engineered for this you can write a simple service. This service should provide an [`Observable`](https://angular.io/guide/observables) which your footer component subscribes to. From the other component now run a function in the service which delivers the next value in the `Observable`.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use HTML [CustomEvents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Listen to event:

```ts
document.addEventListener('my-event', () => {
  console.log('My event !');
});
```

Dispatch event:

```ts
document.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent('my-event') );
```